# Spring-security-ldap: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ldap, wildfly

I am migrating from Jboss 7.1 to Wildfly and getting exception on fail auth.

To login in the system I user spring-security-ldap and cas-client, and when I type wrong password on the login form I get exception:

```
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory from classloa
der ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.gas.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationExceptio
n: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]]
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:99)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:90)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:44)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:43) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.
RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:254) [spring-ldap-core-1.3.1
.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 48 more
```

My module for spring-security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.spring.security" slot="3.1.3">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-ldap-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-security-cas-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="spring-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.spring.core" slot="3.2.1" export="true" />
        <module name="org.jasig.cas.client.cas-client-core" slot="3.1.12" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons-lang" slot="2.5"/>
        <module name="sun.jdk" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Everything was fine at Jboss AS 7.1, may be I forgot to change something in properties?

--- EDIT

All because of org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthentication class:

There is a function bindWithDn(...), that tries to create context with userDnStr and throws exception if can't. I have a list of userDnStr and the first userDnStr (if user doesn't exists at this ldap folder) function throws exception. But on Wildfly it throws org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException instead of AuthenticationException or OperationNotSupportedException as on Jboss 7 / Tomcat

Spring sources:

```
 // This will be thrown if an invalid user name is used and the method may
            // be called multiple times to try different names, so we trap the exception
            // unless a subclass wishes to implement more specialized behaviour.
            if ((e instanceof org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException)
                    || (e instanceof org.springframework.ldap.OperationNotSupportedException)) {
                handleBindException(userDnStr, username, e);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
```

In case of AuthenticationException or OperationNotSupportedException spring can handle it and moves on and tries the next userDnStr.  Still question is: Why getContext() throws UncategorizedLdapException on Wildfly?

Answer (score 0):

The DN should be an admin.  Or allow anonymous binding on the DC.  Don't forget the domain short name shortName\administrator.